# Configuring BOWER install paths

Tags: bower, package-managers, bower-install

I have following bower.json file

```
{
"name" : "learningBower",
"version" : "0.0.0",
"authors" : [
    "G Akshay <g.akshayapps@gmail.com>"
],
"description" : "learning bower",
"license" : "MIT",
"ignore" : [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
],
"dependencies" : {
    "font-awesome" : "~4.3.0"
},
"install" : {
    "path" : {          
        "eot" : "src/fonts",
        "ttf" : "src/fonts",
        "otf" : "src/fonts",
        "woff" : "src/fonts",
        "woff2" : "src/fonts",
        "svg" : "src/fonts"
    }
}
```

I am using using font-awesome and grouping all the font related files under `src/fonts` folder using `bower-installer` package.

1] Is there any way to group all the extensions into one as all are going to end-up in the same path?

2] Also above configuration creates font-awesome folder in `src/fonts` path. In future I am gonna use bootstrap which will come with its glyph fonts and for it another bootstrap folder would be created in `src/fonts`. Is there a way to skip this new folder creation for each new dependency?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, `grunt-contrib-copy` serves the purpose to copy the dependencies to desired location. Takes much time for the first time configuration, but is smooth later on.

So, instead using `bower-installer`, let the bower install dependencies to its default folder `bower-components` which later on would be copied back to desired location.